# open a file in C inside a function and use it outside

Tags: c, file, pointers

trying to open files inside a function in c:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    // check args
    FILE *input = NULL;
    FILE *output = NULL;
    checkArgs(argc, argv, &input, &output);

   if (input != NULL){
       paresInputFile(input);
   }else{
      printf("NULL");
   }


void checkArgs(int argc, char *argv[], FILE **output, FILE **input){
    // validate arguments...
    *input = fopen(argv[2],"r");
    return;
}
```

Im getting some command line arguments.. and I'm using a function that validates them, if they are ok, I try to open 2 files one for output one for input,

How can I use those open files, outside from my checkArgs function,
The way I'm doing it now, they are not accesiable in my main function - I get NULL, if I try to access the file from within my checkArgs function it works fine

Comment: I suppose this serves to illustrate why using so called "out parameters" is not generally recommended: it can make it hard to directly see what a function actually does. An alternative for this code might be to make the `checkArgs` function return `struct args { FILE *input; FILE *output; }` by value...

Answer (score 2):

Your function defines the `output` to be passed first, and the `input` second, but you are passing the pointers in reverse when calling the function.

Comment: wow! thx.. stupid mistake.. been staring at it for a long time and didnt see it

Answer (score 1):

You have just passed input to output and vice versa .
Corrected your program as below . It should work .

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    // check args
    FILE *input = NULL;
    FILE *output = NULL;
    checkArgs(argc, argv,  &output,&input,);//corrected this line 

   if (input != NULL){
       paresInputFile(input);
   }else{
      printf("NULL");
   }


void checkArgs(int argc, char *argv[], FILE **output, FILE **input){
    // validate arguments...
    *input = fopen(argv[2],"r");
    return;
}
```